# Identify all files or folder which contains a specific keyword

Tags: shell, sh

Using a script need to identify all files or folder which contains a specific keyword under given path. The path will have multiple folders.
Below is the script that is used.

```
   #!/bin/sh
   DIR=''
   for FILE in ls "$DIR"*
   do
           # echo $FILE
               grep -l $FILE "*FY*"
    done
~
```

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
   DIR=''
   for FILE in ls "$DIR"*
   do
           # echo $FILE
               grep -l $FILE "*FY*"
    done
~

Comment: The above one is the script i am using but is not working. Need help in that.

Comment: @lakshmisowmya I think your teacher either wants you to use a recursive function or use `find`, depending on what you’ve learned so far.

Comment: @lakshmisowmya Did You Know™ that you can [edit] the question to include your code, rather than post it in a comment where it’s hard to read?

Comment: @Biffen: Can you explain what is the difference between grep and find command?

Comment: @lakshmisowmya I’d rather not. It’s basic stuff and you should be able to look it up on your own.

Comment: @ChristinaJacob: the command is searching for all letters in pattern. I need only exact word searching.

Comment: @lakshmisowmya do some research there is options for that in the manual I linked in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the "keyword" before the path to be searched. which it not the case in your script.

```
  grep -l -r "keyword" path/to/folder
```

Try the above script.

```
-l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input
          file  from  which  output would normally have been printed.  The
          scanning will stop on the first  match.   (-l  is  specified  by
          POSIX.)

-R, -r, --recursive
          Read all  files  under  each  directory,  recursively;  this  is
          equivalent to the -d recurse option.
```

for more info [refer](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html)